# How to integrate Adobe Sign on SharePoint 2013 On-Premise?

Tags: sharepoint, adobe

I need to integrate Adobe Sign on SharePoint 2013 On-premise, do I need to install it on all servers in the Farm or only to the Application Server?

Answer (score 0):

The integration with SharePoint is a farm solution. Have you had a look at the installation documentation and the installation package?

- Current package (https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/sign/AdobeSign_for_SharePoint_4_0_0_1.zip)
- Documentation (https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/help/adobe_sign_for_sharepoint_installation_guide.html)